# Answer up/down vote count not being returned in filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, filter, answers

[image: Vote count selected but not returned?]

As the picture shows, the `up_vote_count` and `down_vote_count` answer properties are selected but not returned.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this has been deployed.

The bug was that we were returning partially hydrated answer objects on that particular method.  Building answers is typically a three step process, and we were stopping on step 2 effectively.

Comment: Awesome!  Now, I can get back to implementing cool features for my app.  Thanks.